# What do char variables with values lower than 0x20 get converted to?

Tags: c, char, ascii

I've been developing some c code that sends and receives command packets to an FPGA using a uart serial port. Essentially the code reads a byte at a time from the serial port and stores the values into a buffer.

Example code (my code is fairly similar to this):

```
for (i = 0; i<cmd_len; i++){
   buf[i] = inbyte();
```

This is just a basic example to illustrate the idea, and isn't super indicative of my actual code. `inbyte()` comes from the Xilinx library, it just reads from a memory mapped register.

The problem that I've run into is when I try to send a byte of the command that is under 0x20, the byte isn't printed out. Since my buffer is a char buffer, my guess is that since values below 0x20 on the ascii table aren't really characters, these bytes get discarded. I've also tried using uint8_t to no avail, and Xilinx's u8 expands to a unsigned char anyway.

Would it be accurate to say values under 0x20 simply are "discarded"? If so, is there some way around this? Thanks.

Additional info: I'm using teraterm to connect to a com port, and sending bin files to simulate the hex commands.

Edit: I've printed out the buffer using hex formatting. However it seems the issue is with the receive. I've noticed is that the loop will only iterate for bytes above 0x20, e.g if I send a 16 byte command of 14 0x0's, the for loop will only iterate 2 times. My guess is that something occurs with the `inbyte()` function.

Comment: These characters are control characters and are invisible, the bytes should remain in your buffer but you are unable to print them, try iterating though your buffer printing the byte values rather than characters.

Comment: _"Would it be accurate to say values under 0x20 simply are "discarded"?"_ -- No, that would be highly inaccurate. Values under 0x20 are perfectly fine as `char` values. Something else is going on in your code. When you say that the byte "doesn't show up in the buffer", how are you determining this? What is in the buffer instead?

Comment: No they are probably not discarded, they are simply not displayed. Did you check the contents of the buffer e.g in hexadecimal ?

Comment: how are you sending that command? using string functions may mangle it, since (as you're finding out), not all ascii chars are printable, and some have specific command/control meanings

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking of it completely wrong then. However, I'm using `xil_printf` with a format of `0x%02x`, which should display right? And sorry, by "doesn't show up" I mean that nothing is printed out. That being said, I have a `for loop` like the example, which prints the `"i"` of the for loop, and if I send a 16 byte command, the `"i"` only goes up the 2-3 control bytes I send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not discarded but the thing you are outputting them to might treat them differently. For example 0x07 might cause you computer to beep.

In the old 7 bit ascii days they were referred to as control characters.

Comment: They are still referred to as control characters in Unicode.